# How can I assign a variable to a Console.ReadLine(); response?

Tags: c#

I'm using C# and a console application to ask the user a question and receive their response using:
`Console.ReadLine();`
I know when you are reading a single key you can do this:
`ConsoleKeyInfo variableName = Console.ReadKey(true);` 
But when I do that with Console.ReadLine();...
`ConsoleKeyInfo variableName = Console.ReadLine()`

I get the following error message: 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to System.ConsoleKeyInfo"

So the question is, how can I assign a variable to a Console.ReadLine(); response that the user writes?

Comment: `string result = Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: ReadLine returns string, not ConsoleKeyInfo. Just look at method declaration more attentively.

Comment: Learning to read documentation is a useful skill to have...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Console.ReadLine returns a `string`, not an object of type `ConsoleKeyInfo`.  So the only thing you have to change is the type of the variable to `string`:

```
string variableName = Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string result = Console.ReadLine();
```

See also the [Console.ReadLine documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> **Return Value**
>
> Type: System.String
>
> The next line of characters from the input stream, or null if no more lines are available.

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to System.ConsoleKeyInfo"

You get this error because `Console.ReadLine();` has the return type string. This can be solved by using:

```
string result = Console.ReadLine();
```

or

```
var result = Console.ReadLine();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var